# Plotting a matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a matrix row by row.  The first row I would like to plot then right next to it I would like to plot the next row of information. It is a big matrix it is 287x6.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: How do you you want the resulting plot to look like? Can you give an example for a small matrix to clarify your question?

Comment: An example of what I want to do is if I have a matrix A = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3; 4 4 4] I want to plot the set of the first row then the set of the second row and keep going so I want to plot 1 1 1 1 then 2 2 2 2 then 3 3 3 3. Is that more clear? Sorry I'm not good with computer programming language. I can try to make it more clear.

Comment: Instead of trying to explain it in words, can you add an image of a sample plot to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like a surface plot, or just a large set of line plots? Depending on what your data represents, different approaches are of course more or less appropriate.

For line plots, you could do something like

```
figure, hold on
for row=1:size(A,1)
    plot(A(row,:))
end
```

although I doubt that would be legible. To do a surface plot, the easiest is just to do

```
surf(A)
```

in which case you'll have row index on one axis, column index on the other, and the matrix element values on the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> m = magic(10);
>> s = size(m);
>> for i=1:s(1)
plot(i,m(i,:),'o'); hold on
end
```

[image]